# Bypass login with mqsql_fetch_object - Sql injection

Tags: sql-injection

I have the following PHP Code and I am not able to pass the authentication using a SQL Injection. Do you have any ideas how to do it?

```
$password=md5($_REQUEST['dr']);
$result=mysql_query("SELECT dr FROM table WHERE user='".$username."'");
if (mysql_fetch_object($result)->dr==$password) {
            $okay=true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a SQL Injection obviously on `$username` parameter, but you can't bypass login, because the password is compared with the result of the query, for example, if you inject `' or 1=1 --`, the query will be:

```
SELECT dr FROM table WHERE user='' or 1=1 --
```

But this doesn't mean you can access to the application, the following line code shows how the result of the query is compared with the parameter `dr`:

```
if (mysql_fetch_object($result)->dr==$password) {
            $okay=true;
}
```

This is part of the best prractices about login based on SQL queries; compare username and password independently.

I hope this information helps you.